# JPEG headers missing/corrupted

Tags: header, jpeg

I have a 130kb jpeg image that wont open in anything and I need to fix it. From the various image recovery softwares that I used all I got was "Image headers corrupted/missing". I dont even get anything when I look up in the properties of the file, no dimensions etc., just the file size. Is it possible to recover the image once its headers are lost? I dont want to use any recovery softwares anymore. I got one idea from a colleague to parse the jpeg and look for  anomalies compared to a working jpeg. Any other ideas?

Comment: If the file is only missing the header info, then you may be able to restore it. If this JPEG was generated by a digital camera or software which uses fixed Huffman tables, you can take the header info from another image generated by the same camera/software and graft it on to your file to restore it. If you can post the file, I can let you know if it is beyond repair.

Answer (score 1):

The only method I can think of is to look at the JPEG using a hex editor, and check if its contents conform to the [JPEG spec](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf). Good luck.